# django-import-export ForeignKey widget returns empty values (Django 1.10)

Tags: python-3.x, django-1.10, django-import-export

I'm trying to export Student, which has a OneToOne relationship with Django built-in **User** model. But when I export Students, the username column is empty in the exported file.

```
# models.py    
class Student(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_('user'))
        student_number = models.CharField(unique=True, null=False, max_length=10, verbose_name=_('student number'))
        score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_('score'))

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.get_full_name()

# admin.py
class StudentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    username = fields.Field(column_name='username', attribute='User',
               widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(model=User, field='username'))

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'student_number', 'score',)

class StudentAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    resource_class = StudentResource

admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

I get result when replace `StudentResource` class with this:

```
class StudentResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id', 'user__username', 'student_number', 'score',)
```

but then I would have problem when importing data. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is about the capitalized 'User' in `attribute='User'` in `username` field. I thought it might be good to explain more about using `ForeignKeyWidget`.

To use `ForeignKeyWidget` you should specify these elements:

- Specify a `column_name`  which is the name of the column in your import/export file.
- In `attribute`, determine the name of the field of your **current model**, which is a `OneToOneField` or a `ForeignKey`. In my case it is `user` in `Student` model.
- In `ForeignKeyWidget` specify the name of related model and one of its fields which you want to get data from. In my case the related model is `User` and the field is its `username` field.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Your explanation is better than the official django-import-export documentation.